# Creating custom task in new file?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Im trying to set up a new custom task, I want it in a different file so I have this code:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.registerMultiTask('test-task', 'this is a test',     

    function() {
        console.log('all ok');
    });
};
```

In a file relative to Gruntfile.js here:

```
tasks/test.js
```

In my Gruntfile I have:

```
grunt.loadTasks('tasks/test');
```

And then:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['test-task']);
```

But I get the error that the task can not be found.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you check your error log?

Comment: How can i check that? Whats the flag?

Answer (score 0):

`grunt.loadTasks` expects a directory to search in.

Instead just require the file since it is registering the tasks on its own.

```
require('tasks/test');
```

Comment: Updated. just use `require('tasks/test');`

Answer (score 0):

Specify the directory instead of the specific file.  Assuming your task is located in `myproject/tasks/test.js`, and your gruntfile.js is in `myproject/`, your loadTasks call should look like this:

```
grunt.loadTasks('tasks');
```